# How to convert hours from a starting date to year, month, and day

Tags: python, datetime

The data below are hours starting from 1800:00:00.0

I am trying to convert them to day, month, and year starting from the above date.

```
1.52887e+06
1.52959e+06
1.53034e+06
1.53108e+06
1.5318e+06
1.53254e+06
1.53326e+06
1.53401e+06
1.53475e+06
1.53542e+06
1.53617e+06
1.53689e+06
1.53763e+06
```

I want to convert them to day, month, and year from that starting date.

thanks

Comment: User the base `datetime` and then add a`timedelts` to it? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please could you put it in a small code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `datetime` module, the `timedelta` method is used to add the hours to the starting date to get the converted dates.

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(1800, 1, 1)
dates = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(hours=hour) for hour in hours]

for date in dates:
    print(date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:

```
31 May 1974 22:00:00
30 Jun 1974 22:00:00
01 Aug 1974 04:00:00
01 Sep 1974 00:00:00
01 Oct 1974 00:00:00
31 Oct 1974 20:00:00
30 Nov 1974 20:00:00
01 Jan 1975 02:00:00
31 Jan 1975 22:00:00
28 Feb 1975 20:00:00
01 Apr 1975 02:00:00
01 May 1975 02:00:00
31 May 1975 22:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = datetime(year=1800, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
formatted_dates =[]

for hour in hours:
    date = start_date + timedelta(hours=hour)
    formatted_dates.append("{0}-{1}-{2}".format(date.day, date.month, date.year))
print(formatted_dates)
```

---

```
['31-5-1974', '30-6-1974', '1-8-1974', '1-9-1974', '1-10-1974', '31-10-1974', '30-11-1974', '1-1-1975', '31-1-1975', '28-2-1975', '1-4-1975', '1-5-1975', '31-5-1975']
```